# How to don't show SAMBA authentication window for Anonymous user?

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, authentication

My network disk is no need any authentication. I connect this disk as **client** from Ubuntu 18.04. Windows machines in same network can connect him without any issues or additional questions. It possible do not show this window in case no password (Anonymous user):

[image: SAMBA authentication for Anonymous user]

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba 4 made changes to how it deals with passwords so you will always have to pass credentials when accessing a share even if it means using **anonymous** for public shares.

If you think about it it is doing exactly what Windows does in this situation. When Windows accesses a share it automatically - and without the users knowledge - passes the users current username and password to the server. If there is no match on the server the user is designated a "guest" and if the share permits it will gain access to the share. The point here is that Windows always sends a user name and password to the server.

Samba thinks this automatic passing of local user names and passwords is goofy so it will prompt you for it instead - even if it means selecting "anonymous"

For a frequently used share you only have to do it once:

For Connect As: use **guest**

For Password: use **xxx**

Then select **Remember forever**

Comment: For this to work, it needs certain options in smb.conf. For me, I think the key was to have `map to guest = Bad User` (previously I managed to have anonymous connect succesfully by using "guest account = _actual owner of the shared directory_`, I think.